# SP Document Set Welcome Page - Additional Look and Feel Needs

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-set, sharepoint-rest-api

I was reviewing a Q & A on this site discussing a nice way to update the look and feel of the Document Set properties using REST API and jQuery. You can see what I am referring to by going [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/159748/document-set-properties-look-and-feel). His (almost) final result gave me hope that I can accomplish what I am trying to do with my site.

I will preface my question by saying I am doing all of this in SharePoint Online / O365.

What I am trying to do is capture the Title, Description, and an additional column added to the Document Set, and display it on the Welcome Page of the document set. I know that information shows up through the Document Set Properties web part, but I have no way of adjusting the look and feel of how it is presented on the site. I also know that this works with the code provided from the Q & A I posted above; however, I will have over 2000 document sets in one document library. I need to pull the specific information for that specific document set I am currently on.

Here is my 'possible' idea on how this could be done (although I don't know how to do it) -

- Run some javascript to figure out which document set you are currently on (using the Name or Title site column). Store that result, then use API to pull all metadata related to the Document Set you are on with a filter that will only return the information based on the Name or Title you just find above.

Basically, I believe the only way for this to happen is for the code to figure out what document set I am in, get the properties of that document set from API or another place, and then allow me to display those results in the web part - probably using jQuery and HTML.

Hopefully that makes sense. Anyone have any ideas? Need me to clarify anything?

Thanks in advance.